# preserving whitespace in/around nested Bold tags

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some xaml code for a silverlight project sort of like below:

```xml
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph>
            <Bold>Note: </Bold>This is an important message!
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that regardless of where I put the whitespace in/around the Bold tag, i can't get a space before the 'T' in 'This'. Is there a more elegant solution than just using the xml:space="preserve" property on the parent  tag? Because then I have to remove all tabbing before the  tags with this issue, which sort of destroys the hierarchical view of the xml itself.

To be clear, I know this solution below works:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox>
            <Paragraph xml:space="preserve">
<Bold>Note:</Bold> This is an important message!
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
```

But i'm interested in knowing if there is a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing

Comment: I can't reproduce the "no spaces", perhaps there is a space and it just isn't big enough to see? You could use `&#160;` as a non-breaking space instead.

Comment: How about 

    `<Bold xml:space="preserve">Note: </Bold>This is an important message! `

Makes it a bit more obvious?

Comment: @Ben +1 and this is actually the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph>
            <Bold xml:space="preserve">Note: </Bold>This is an important message!
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Makes it a bit more obvious where you need space preserved?

Comment: wow... that is embarrassingly obvious now that I look at it. thanks!